# What is the meaning of <E> in MyList<E>?

Tags: java, generics

I really don't get the meaning of E in this interface. I have been searching but no luck so far. Can someone pls explain it.

```
public interface MyList<E> {
    int getSize();
    void insert(MyList<?> data) throws ListOverflowException;
    E getElement(E data) throws NoSuchElementException;
    boolean delete(E data); // returns false if the data is not deleted in the list
    boolean search(E data);
}
```

Comment: Its a generic. So the user, who implements this interface, can choose a type. `E` itself is a placeholder for the type. For example, a class could do `class StringList implements MyList<String> { ... }`. Id suggest you lookup a tutorial about generics.

Comment: There is an issue at the `insert` method. It shouldnt take `MyList<?> data` but `MyList<? extends E> data`. Otherwise its unsafe. Remember **PECS**.

Comment: The `getElement` method seems odd to me. It should probably take an index instead, so `E getElement(int index)`. Or should be changed to a `contains` method like `boolean contains(E element)`.

Comment: See [Lesson: Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Got it lemme revise seems like I revised the insert method by mistake. Well, this code was from my programming assignment.